# Replace newline character with ',' in Notepad or BBEdit or using Unix command `tr`?

Tags: unix, notepad, tr, bbedit

I have to replace the newline character with ',' for using in some oracle command but in a single command. I can't figure out how to do it.

Input:

```
R1
R2
R3
R4
```

Required Output:

```
'R1','R2','R3','R4'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `tr`:

```
cat data.txt | tr '\n' ','
```

If you need the quotes, you could pipe to `sed`:

```
cat data.txt | tr '\n' ',' | sed "s/,/','/g"
```

… which gets you pretty close:

```
R1','R2','R3','R4','
```

Comment: I am new to unix so could not understand why we can not directly replace newline with ',' characters

Answer (score 4):

In BBedit, you would use a grep like these for find:

```
(R[0-9]+)\r
```

and replace:

```
'\1',
```

Answer (score 2):

Using sed:

```
 sed -n '1h;1!H;${ g; s/\n/,/g; s/\([^,]*\)/'\''\1'\''/gp}' input
```

Comment: Thanks for replying ...
while firing the command on terminal I am getting an error:" sed: 1: "1h;1!H;${ g; s/\n/,/g;  ...": bad flag in substitute command: '}'"

Comment: it works even when I disable gnu extensions. Are you missing something during copy-paste?

Comment: I have pasted the following " sed -n '1h;1!H;${ g; s/\n/,/g; s/\([^,]*\)/'\''\1'\''/gp}' <aitr"

where aitr is my file name

Comment: @Jagdeep: You are missing the escapes before the parentheses. `([^,]*)` needs to be `\([^,]*\)`

Comment: I am pasting correctly on the terminal using escapes properly but while pasting here in the comment it is escaping the value...

Comment: This looks wrong: `s/([^,]*)/` it needs to be `s/\([^,]*\)/`.

Comment: @Jagdeep, what is the output of `echo $SHELL` on your terminal?

Comment: @perreal: o/p is /bin/bash

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way using `sed`:

```
sed ":a;N;\$!ba;s/\n/','/g;s/^\|$/'/g" file
```

Results:

```
'R1','R2','R3','R4'
```

Comment: Thanks for replying 
while firing the command I am getting an error; "-bash: !ba: event not found"

Answer (score 1):

The requirement to replace newlines does not match your sample output.  To replace newlines with `,`, you can do `tr \\n ,`, but this gives you output with a trailing comma that does not have a trailing newline.  Also, it does not quote your input.  Perhaps you are looking for:

```
paste -s -d, input
```

Or, if you do actually want the fields to be quoted:

```
< input sed "s/^\|$/'/g" | paste -s -d,
```

In the above, your input file is named `input`.  The final command can also be written:

```
sed "s/^\|$/'/g" input | paste -s -d,
```